# one click removing the entire text from a text-field

Tags: html, mobile-application, webapp-net

I have the following codes, its part of the application I am building for iPhone/android phones.

```
<li><span>X</span><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" id="anum" maxlength="9" placeholder="Account Number""/></li>
<li><span>X</span><input type="text" id="bname" placeholder="Beneficiary Name" /></li>
```

the "X" between the spans is suppose to appear when on a keyboard a button is pressed. after the "x" has appeared the user can remove the entire text in that field by pressing on the "x". when there is no element in the field at all, the "x" is not visible. But i cant make it happen.

I am using webapp-net. I would be glad if some could help me with this.

Comment: What do you have until now? Give us something to bootstrap the idea.

Comment: I know that I have to use onkeydown, but I dont know how to make the x appear when a key is pressed, and how to make it disappear when there is no element in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not either quite familiar with WebApp.Net, but you might consider on using a form and a reset button, such as:

```
<input type="button" value="X" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
```

or something like:

```
<input type="reset" value="X">
```

inside of a `<form>` with the rest text inputs, and having in mind an html-like enviroment (even thought this might not clear a radio/checkbox inputs).

If I haven't got you wrong, you might also consider on looking if there is something like placeholders for textareas and/or text inputs on that framework. Good luck.